# session mismatch in jsp servlet on apache tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, session, tomcat, servlets

I am facing a very strange problem in my application which works fine, but sometimes i have to face a problem.

I have an application running on apache tomcat, the problem is of session. when i login to my application, i store user name in session, there are 100-200 users login to my application daily.

There is a module in my application that prints the cash receipt, here is the actual problem, sometime it prints the user name of another user. Suppose the logged in user name is `adam` but it prints the name `john` that is another user.

It happens rarely, also I have noticed that when I restart my tomcat server then this problem encountered.

Is this the problem of apache tomcat or something about related to my code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and check if yours can be improved.

Comment: offcourse problem will be in your code, please post code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for session hijacking attempts. Store the ipaddress and user-agent in the session at login.  For all subsequent calls, at the top of each page, check that the ipaddress and user-agent in the request match those in the session.  If not, invalidate the session and redirect to login page (to kick the user out).